# Autocomplete stops working after approximately 200 text input boxes in a form

Tags: html, autocomplete

I am creating a very large web form and I want the input boxes to autocomplete. I use a table within the form to hold all of the input boxes. My code has this general structure:

```
<form method="get" autocomplete="on">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Label:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="unique_relevant_name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Label:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="unique_relevant_name"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Label:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="unique_relevant_name"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

I need the table structure because it organizes the page in a specific way using CSS. The autocomplete works well for around 200 input boxes. However, when I add an additional input box at a certain point (let's say the 201st input box), it stops working. In other words, no new entries are saved and included in the autocomplete when I submit the form, as they are when they're working correctly. Even in input boxes that were working once before, stop working. Once I delete this new entry, it goes back to normal. I really don't think it's a syntax error because I am literally copying and pasting working code and then it doesn't work. Therefore, I'm trying to learn more about the autocomplete... is there a limit to how many input boxes it can work with? I am thinking about switching to JavaScript options but I want to know why this won't work.

Comment: I noticed this. It's very difficult to find documentation on this.